# Convert image file to webp on upload

Tags: php, upload, type-conversion, gd, webp

Trying to write script which will *convert image type (gif, jpeg, jpg,png) to webP* in addition to *uploading original file for fallback* in browsers not supporting webP (earlier versions of Safari, etc.)

**In attempting to get this to work I have:**

1. built a script which takes all image types and uploads them successfully to server, saving three different sized thumbnails for various purpose.
2. enable gd library on my local mamp server (6.4) running on OS X/Mac
3. Read a great deal about webP
4. attempted several tutorials / disceted a bunch of examples
5. attempted to research my error - found little reference on web that was useful

Multiple attempts to hand the data off have lead me to attempt to do so as a trying so I can use the *imagewebp($imgWEBP, $uploadPATH)* to convert & upload the image to the server from the local host/desktop of the user to the site server image directory. Other attempts to convert the image using a more direct handoff *$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['image']['name']* have failed; Currently I'm trying to save the image in a folder in same directory as script, I'll re-path later once script is working properly.

I believe the reoccurring problem causing the error is in the handoff of the image source/data so the image data can be converted to webP and uploaded to server.

The tutorials and examples i have found dont' address how to hand the data off in an acceptable way, they all start with the data as being in that form an don't tell you what the form it.

I have gotten very far in this script, it's my most advanced script I've tried to do so far. First time trying to use GD library. I am a novice and probably way over my head, but trying, i'm hoping that I can get the proper guidance to solve the error type issue (Type must be GdImage, string given)

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
#  save image file given from upload form to server in webP format
function   sv___asWEBP ($source, $fileEXTN, $pathSOURCE, $pathUPLOAD, $quality,   $cont= '', $myIMAGE='') {

# var_dump($source);
#die;
#$a_$fileEXTN = pathinfo($source, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($fileEXTN == 'jpeg' || $fileEXTN == 'jpg'){
     
    $myIMAGE = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    ob_start();
        imagejpeg($myIMAGE,NULL,100);
        $cont =  ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
        imagedestroy($myIMAGE);
    }

if($fileEXTN == 'gif'){ 
    $myIMAGE = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    }

if($fileEXTN == 'png'){
    $myIMAGE = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    }

#  convert data to string to attempt convert to webP format
$content =  imagecreatefromstring($cont);

# convert string to webP save to server
$imgWEBP  = imagewebp($cont,  $pathSOURCE); # <=== line #415

# upload / save image to server
imagewebp($imgWEBP, $pathUPLOAD);

#  free resources
imagedestroy($imgWEBP);
}//  sv___asWEBP
```

To summarize, problem is in a nutshell, attempt to hand off  image file to imagewebP function fails. All attempts produce the same error 'Uncaught TypeError: imagewebp(): Argument #1 ($image) must be of type GdImage, string given'. Error happens on line #415 -- (SEE code -- line has '# <=== is line 50' to call out where error happens). Looking for help resolving this error. Been working on this for several days - total newb here.

```
FULL ERROR MESSAGE
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: imagewebp(): Argument #1 ($image) must be of type GdImage, string given in .../a_test/aaaSTORE.php:415 
Stack trace: #0 ...aaaSTORE.php(415): imagewebp('\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00...', '/Applications/M...') 
#1 .../a_test/aaaSTORE.php(308): sv___asWEBP('/Applications/M...', 'jpg', '/Applications/M...', './a_uploads/bob...', 80) 
#2 ...aaaSTORE.php(121): ex___imgRESIZE(75, 75, 'jpg', '210802205802', './a_uploads/bob...', 'bob_burgerston-...') 
#3 ...aaa.php(1): include('/Applications/M...') 
#4 {main} thrown in ...aaaSTORE.php on line 415
```

Comment: The return value of `imagecreatefromjpeg($source)`, as long as it isn't `false`, is what you want to pass to `imagewebp()`

Comment: Good to know, I'm not sure what that means, but it gives me a new direction in which to explore for a solution. Thank you @ChrisHass